# Get the top answerers for a tag

Tags: support

How can I get a listing of the top 10 answerers for the [xslt] tag on SO?

I know this link will get the top 10 overall, so how do I modify it for just one particular tag:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27974/top-answerers-of-so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the [particular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C). On the top right, you see the again with a link saying `about`. Click that and you can see the `Top Answerers` for that particular tag

[image]

Now, in the resultant window,

[image]

Comment: Actually, there is a [top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/topusers) link below tag description that brings up the necessary information immediately...